# Sorting users from api into blocks by month of birth

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Beginner at js. 
There are such tasks. Unfortunately, I got stuck after importing users from api

```
        function App() {
  const [users, setUser] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://....api.users'
    );

    setUser(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Users list</h1>
            <div>


        <br />
      </div>
      <div className="users">
        {users &&
          users.map((user, index) => {
            const cleanedDate = new Date(user.released).toDateString();
            const name = user.firstName;

            return (
              <div className="user" key={index}>
                <h3>user {index + 1}</h3>
                <h2>{user.name}</h2>

                <div className="details">
                  <p>id: {user.id}</p>
                  <p>firstName: {user.firstName}</p>
                  <p>lastName: {user.lastName}</p>
                  <p>⏰: {user.dob}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

1) Download the list of users with api
2) display the list of months
3) highlight the months depending on the number of people born this month.
4) When hovering over a selected month, display a list of people who were born this month.

example of user element:  {
    "id": "5e00928d43fcdd11688a6afd",
    "firstName": "Moody",
    "lastName": "Gordon",
    "dob": "2019-11-09T20:20:43.744Z"
  }

Sorry for the banal question
What functionality should be  to bring users into blocks (months of birth)?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First problem to solve is to get month from еру date of birth. 
It can be achieved this way (+1 needed because month count starts from zero):

```
var date = new Date(user.released)
var month = date.getMonth() + 1
```

Then, you have to turn your users array to dictionary wheку key is month number and value is user itself

```
const usersByMonth = users.reduce((result, user) => {
   const monthNumber = new Date(user.released).getMonth() + 1;
   result[monthNumber] = user;
   return result
})
```

Reduce works pretty much the same as

```
let usersByMonth = {};
for(let i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    const monthNumber = new Date(user.released).getMonth() + 1;
    usersByMonth[monthNumber] = user;
}
```

After that you should just simply:

```
return (
    <div className="january">usersByMonth["1"].map...</div>
    <div className="february">usersByMonth["2"].map...</div>
    ...
)
```

Also, you can get user counts by month from this dictionary (usersByMonth) for future use

Comment: Thanks a lot! NOw i have smthng like this and here's a new trouble:to complete paragraphs 3  change color of the month blocks depending on the number of people born this month. and 
4) When hovering over a month block, display a list of people who were born this month. ), I need to write a if else function for an array of months, but I come across errors( 
example: https://jsfiddle.net/4p6d38jn/

thanks for your time!